# email being sent through Google Script is including the source sheet

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation, email-attachments

I created a graduation tracker to help students at my district's HS track their progress towards graduation.  The script below works great- it plugs in the student ID, which generates a custom google sheet specific to the student, creates a PDF, and emails the pdf to the student/ parent email listed in the source sheet.  But... when the email is sent, the source sheet (which has the info for every student in the high school) is also included in the email.  (Edited to add: I've only sent test emails to myself. I don't think that matters, but I don't want to send the file to anyone else until I can be sure the source sheet won't be accidentally included!)

[pic of test email in my inbox showing both the pdf and the source file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyLB9.png)

I tried adjusting the settings for the attachment (specifying it be a pdf, and creating the PDF3 variable which pulls the pdf from the file ID instead of the PDF2 variable).

Any help would be very much appreciated!  I don't have a background in coding, so I'm pretty much learning through trial and error, and I haven't been able to figure out a solution for this problem.

```
function emailGradTrackerPDF() {

///change the text in "" to your template file ID
  const LLMaster = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Grad Tracker");

///CAS = common assessment sheet
  const CAS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Source Sheet").getSheetByName("Test");

///change range in "" to the field you want the student ID number entered into on overview of LL
  const StudentID = "A6"; 

  let data = CAS.getDataRange().getValues();
  data.shift();
  for (let i in data){
    var ss = LLMaster.getSheetByName("Overview");
    ss.getRange(StudentID).setValue(data[i][0]); 
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
    var sourceSheet = LLMaster.getActiveSheet();
    var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + LLMaster.getId() + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
    + '&size=letter' // paper size legal / letter / A4
    + '&portrait=false' // orientation, false for landscape
    + '&fitw=true' // fit to page width, false for actual size
    + '&top_margin=0.2'              
    + '&bottom_margin=0.2'          
    + '&left_margin=0.25'             
    + '&right_margin=0.25'  
    + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    + '&pagenum=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    + '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    + '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER' //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
    + '&vertical_alignment=TOP' //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
      }
    });
    var saveFolder = '2024 PDFs';
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER ID");
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(saveFolder);
      if (folders.hasNext()) {
        folder = folders.next();
      } else {
      folder = parentFolder.createFolder(saveFolder);
     }
    var name = sourceSheet.getRange('N8').getValue();
    var PDF2 = folder.createFile(response.getBlob().setName(name));
    var GT= PDF2.getId();
    var PDF3= DriveApp.getFileById(GT);
  };
    var eRange = sourceSheet.getRange('A8').getValue();
    ///var eRange2 = sourceSheet.getRange('B8').getValue();

    var message = {
      to: eRange,
      subject: "Progress Towards Graduation",
      attachments: [PDF3]
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail(message);
    }
```

Comment: I think that in your showing script, the Spreadsheet is not included in the email. So, I'm worried that your showing script might be different from your actual script for replicating your current issue. How about this? But, if I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Hi Tanaike!  Thank you so much for your reply!   The script I included above is the exact script I am using... I just replaced the file and folder IDs with text.  The spreadsheet is not supposed to be included in the email when I run the script, but it gets sent every time I run the script.  Thanks for your time!  Any additional comments/ suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `The script I included above is the exact script I am using`, I understood it. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation using your showing script. But, I would like to support you. So, I would like to try to correctly replicate your situation. When I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of a solution.